# Setting the default 'From' message header in sendmail without using the -f or -F options

Tags: sendmail

I want sendmail to take all outgoing messages from user32 to be from "John Smith" with email address "jsmith_rocks@hotmail.com". How can I go about that without using the -f and -F sendmail options every time?

Answer (score 1):

If understand you correctly, you can do so by modifying ruleset 0 (or ruleset 1) to rewrite the address:

```
LOCAL_RULE_0
R$* < @ $=w . > $*       jsmith_rocks < @ hotmail.com . > $3
```